# Playstore App Update Rejected - Disclaimer/Source: Missing Clear Source of Information/Disclaimer

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

I've done 10 updates previously for the same app. Now It got rejected for "Missing Clear Source of Information/Disclaimer"

The Message I got

[image: Link]

Also There is no option for me to put disclaimer for a release.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: same. The Alpha was reviewed ok, when I promoted it to Production I received this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that issue by adding privacy policy to my android application.

Now I am able to update my app.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a disclaimer about your application in app description part with full details of your application.
Full details means how the app will work and all the feature you have in your application.

Comment: Thanks for providing this answer, is it possible to annotate it with some screenshots for a fuller answer?

Comment: I had same problem few days ago as yours. Then I updated the descriptions like this. You can see the descriptions here: (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lab69.jobnewsbd)